# How exactly does Gitlab detect languages in a project?

Tags: gitlab, detection

I have been trying to understand how the languages chart (the one on the main page of a project as a line or in Repository > Charts as a circle) works.

It says "Measured in bytes of code. Excludes generated and vendored code." I played with it and this explanation seems inexact. Generated code is counted (at least in Java with @Generated), invalid JS in a .js file is not, comments and blank lines are, ...

Does anyone know how does it really work, or even better, know where I can find the corresponding code in Gitlab's source code so I can understand it myself ? I've looked but could not find it.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think they're using GitHub Linguist https://github.com/github/linguist but it's not explicitly mentioned in their doc https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/#repository-languages

Comment: I didnt know Linguist was from GitHub, thanks ! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: On the page https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/#repository-languages in the example of .gitattributes there is written `*.proto linguist-detectable=true` — in contains the word 'linguist, so in some way this can be considered as 'explicitly mentioned'.